# How many messages will send by MQTT.js at a time?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am using MQTT.js library as a MQTT client in my node app.

I am using Qos 2.

I just need to know if there is any property that controls the number of messages to send at once to the Emq broker.

In low band width like 10kb/s my application not sending data to Emq (The data size for each message is 25kb and there will be only 10 packets every time in the outgoing store).

Comment: You are going to add a lot more context to the question. e.g. What QOS are you using? What do you mean by inflight in this situation? What is the problem you are trying to solve? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59749789/edit) the question with these details.

Comment: What do you mean by the last part (`...each packet is 25kb and only 10 packets...`) Is this a description of the MQTT message size or a limitation of the network hardware?

Comment: Its the size of mqtt message size. My application is publishing 10 messages at a time using client.publish method. My question is whether Mqtt js client has any mechanism to control the number of messages send from client store to brocker at a time.